# Existence of a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\aleph_0$ remainder

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactifications

We know that the space $\mathbb{R}$ has compactifications with one point remainder, and two point remainder. but there is no compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ with three point remainder and the same holds for every finite natural number $n$ greater than 3.
We know that the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite remainder.
(i.e.$|\beta\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{R}|=2^\mathfrak{c}$

I have the same question for  other infinite cardinals less than $2^\mathfrak{c}$ as follows:

A. Is there any compactification $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $|X-\mathbb{R}|=\aleph_0$?

B. Can we improve our question to cardinals less than $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Typo: remainder, not reminder.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain briefly why there is no compactification with $n$ points? 

Comment: Hello Dear Joel David. you can search in the box of my questions. before this question, I posed a question titled by "A question about some special compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$". if it doesn't satisfy you, I can explain it for you. I think I have another interesting proof for your question.
(best wishes)

Comment: The question referred in the previous comment is: [A question about some  special compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/95748).

Comment: Perhaps look at the Bohr compactification.  See if it has cardinal $\mathfrak c$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_compactification  Well, maybe not what you want.  It seems that the map $\mathbb R \to b\mathbb R$ is not homeomorphic to its image, only continuous and injective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are interested in Hausdorff compactifications. (It is easy to construct a non-Hausdorff compactification with 3-point remainder.)

Set $W=\beta\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb R$;
note that $W$ has two connected components.
If $Z$ is an other compactification of $\mathbb R$ then $V=Z\backslash \mathbb R$
is an image of $W$.
Therefore $V$ has at most two connected components.
It follows that cardinality of $V$ may be 1, 2, or something between $\mathfrak{c}$ and $|W|=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Anton Petrunin. your proof is prfect and resonable. But is there any compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ with 
cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: Yes, there are compactifications of $\mathbb R$ whose remainder has cardinality $\mathfrak c$.  Consider, for example, the topologist's sine curve.  More precisely, consider the graph of $y=\sin(1/x)$ for $0<x\leq 1$ together with the vertical segment from $-1$ to 1 on the $y$-axis.  The graph of $y=\sin(1/x)$ for $0<x<1$ is a copy of $\mathbb R$, and I've added one point $(1,\sin 1)$ to compactify it at one end and the vertical segment, of cardinality $\mathfrak c$, to compactify it at the other end.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As Emil pointed out, I misinterpreted a statement in Charalambous article. Corrections are in boldface:

**I don´t know if** The answer to A is yes. For a separable metric space X (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$) the following are equivalent (see *[Compactifications with countable remainder](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1980-0548099-3)* by Charalambous in PAMS 1980):

1. X is Cech-complete and rim-compact.
2. X has a compactification with **at most** countable remainder.

$\mathbb{R}$ is Cech-complete because it is complete, and it is rim-compact because it is locally compact.

**So $\mathbb{R}$ has a compactification with at most countable remainder, but you already knew that.**

Comment:  Hi dear ramiro. thank you very much.But I don't have any thing about this article. please give more information about this article. I have to see how  it proved by Charalambous.  

Comment: Are you sure Charalambous proved that $X$ has a compactification with a countable *infinite* remainder? The paper does not say so (but I haven’t studied the proof to see whether it gives that). This interpretation is suspect, because if $X$ is already compact, it satisfies both conditions, but obviously has no compactification with nonempty remainder.

Comment: Dear ramiro.  your answer doesn't satisfy me. I think the answer of my question must be negative! please defend your Answer in a reasonable way, without refering to this mentioned theorem.